# Backbone collections without server

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

Is it possible to use a collection without any interaction with a server? I know backbone has a local storage option but I'd rather not use that.

Comment: So how had you planned on using it without a server unless you want to use the storage?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, definitely! There aren't a lot of rules when it comes to Backbone, and requiring you to interact with a server isn't one of them.

The `fetch()` and `create()` methods for collections require a url in the collection definition, but if you don't use those methods, you should be fine. For models, avoid `fetch()`, `save()`, and `destroy()`.

If you do need those methods for some reason, you can just set `collection.url = '/'` and it just won't do anything.

Comment: ugh I was hoping to use create without causing an attempted request :( is it possible to do a 'silent' create?

Comment: You could use `collection.add( model )`, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it entirely in memory if you like.

Comment: So would defining a url as a function to return nothing be okay? (error if no url defined for collection on create, sync etc)

Comment: No, just never call `fetch`.